# Floating image with heading with background

Tags: html, css, css-float

Yes! Another floating image problem! Of course there are a lot of questions about this and I read things like: add the image to the background-image property. No can do this time:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzUn/)

**The problem**

I have an image, floated to the left. I have heading next to it. But! When adding a margin-right to the floated image. The text will indeed move away from the image, but the background still continues. I want the background to seperate as well. In the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzUn/)

So I tried a few things like, floating the complete text as well, but of course, the text is dynamic and I can't acertain the true height.

I tried adding the text in a loose div and put it next to it with positions. Doesn't work, because the new div is also 100% width (by definition of H1).

*So what do I actually want?* An image, on the left. Text next to it, with a heading. The heading is stretched between the image(+margin-right) and the end of the div it is in.

For people who are too lazy to click my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzUn/):

```
<div class="main">
    <div><img src="http://www.freakingnews.com/images/app_images/banana.jpg" class="banana"></div>
    <div class="textBox">
        <h1>The title of the banana BLA</h1>
        A lot of text is placed in here, because it is nice to have a lot of text. And more of course.
    </div>
</div>

.banana
{
    width:200px;
    margin-right:2em;
    float:left;
}

.textBox
{
    width:400px;
    background-color:red;
}

.main
{
    background-color:green;
}

h1
{
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

PS. I don't like height hacks with JS. I *do* like hacks with css and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.banana {
    width:200px;
    padding-right:2em;
    float:left;
}

.textBox {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
}

.main {
    background-color:green;   
}
```

You must specify the width of both of the `div` elements. If you don't, the second `div` that is not floated will start from the top-left of the containing `div`!

**Note:** if the width of the 2 `div` elements is larger than the container `div`, you end up with one above the other.

Comment: Almost seems to be doing what I want. Only now, the main div is empty. Everything is floated outside. So the height of my main is 0 and should be auto height.

Comment: I modified your stylesheet with some extra properties. **`overflow: auto;`** seems to be very important for margins. And added some `clear:both` statesments. The `div`s are still height:0, but that is something I can't avoid I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually got what you want if i put everything in a html document and run it instead of using jsFiddle

Comment: @tobobooga It doesn't work in FF. The header background continues underneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

[This works!](http://jsfiddle.net/P6uP2/) I got carried away... this is HTML5. Can you tell me if this works on IE7-8? I am on a Mac so I do not have IE.

If it doesn't work, try adding the following markup  in your document header: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">`.

---

### HTML

```
<section id="main">
    <article id="banana">
        <section>
            <img src="http://www.freakingnews.com/images/app_images/banana.jpg"/>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </header>
            <p>
                Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! Some paragraph! 
            </p>
        </section>
    </article>

</section>
```

---

### CSS

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
}

#main h1 {
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: left;
}

#banana {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
}

#banana img {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

#banana section {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#banana h1 {
    color: white;
}

#banana p {
    color: gray;
}
```

---

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't even work in FF. The text and header are underneath the image.

Comment: @Marnix: Like I said this is HTML5.. and FF does not support HTLM5. Try it out in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari or Opera. Replace the <section> and <article> tags with <div>.

Comment: **FF does not support as much HTML5 as Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: I also tried to convert this bit of code to HTML4, using divs and all, but it didn't work out either. But I see that some things you try are good. Like `float:left;` with `overflow:auto;`